# Trim column X leaving a specific number of chatacters if column Y and column Z are not equal to NULL

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I am trying to find a way to use awk/sed to filter a csv to truncate the value in a specific column such as column 1 to retain the last 8 characters and replace the beginning with a wildcard, only if two other specific columns are not equal to NULL- such as col 3 and col 5

Example data:

```
1597012957a0dg9a0t593qa_filename1.exe,NULL,NULL,DATA,NULL,DATA
asvasihtiqsafsoithqwtoihwoi_filename2.exe,NULL,DATA,DATA,DATA,DATA
```

Would become:

```
1597012957a0dg9a0t593qa_filename1.exe,NULL,NULL,DATA,NULL,DATA
*.filename2.exe,NULL,DATA,DATA,DATA,DATA
```

I have scripted this using a series of pipping `rev` and `cut`, but it is terribly inefficent and I am in the process of learning more advanced `awk`/`sed` filters as I am processing a lot of data and the script takes hours.

Comment: `.filename2.exe` is not 8 characters, it's 14 characters

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you want. Do you want the last 8 chars of the first field (e.g. `ame2.exe`)? or do you want to remove everything up to and including the underscore (e.g. `filename2.exe`)?   Also do you want the first field to be modified only if **both** the 3rd and 5th fields don't contain "NULL", or if either of them contain something other than NULL (i.e. should this be an AND or an OR operation)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -v c=8 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }
$3!="NULL" && $5!="NULL"{ $1=(length($1)>c?"*"substr($1,length($1)-c+1):$1) }1' infile
```

here we add "*" only if length of the column#1>8 characters (you can change in `c=#` for how many characters you want retain) else print the column#1 unchanged.

Comment: This solution is exactly what I was looking for, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Using perl:

1. replacing everything in first field up to `_` character, logical AND (`&&`) - i.e. both have to not be "NULL":

```
$ perl -F, -pe 's/^.*?_/*/ if ($F[2] ne "NULL" && $F[4] ne "NULL")' input.csv 
1597012957a0dg9a0t593qa_filename1.exe,NULL,NULL,DATA,NULL,DATA
*filename2.exe,NULL,DATA,DATA,DATA,DATA
asvasihtiqsafsoithqwtoihwoi_filename2.exe,NULL,NULL,DATA,DATA,DATA
asvasihtiqsafsoithqwtoihwoi_filename2.exe,NULL,DATA,DATA,NULL,DATA
```

This uses perl's "non-greedy" `?` quantifier with `.*` so that it matches only up to the first (and presumably only) underscore character.

2. replacing everything in first field up to `_` character, logical OR (`||`), i.e. either or both of them have to not be "NULL":

```
$ perl -F, -pe 's/^.*?_/*/ if ($F[2] ne "NULL" || $F[4] ne "NULL")' input.csv 
1597012957a0dg9a0t593qa_filename1.exe,NULL,NULL,DATA,NULL,DATA
*filename2.exe,NULL,DATA,DATA,DATA,DATA
*filename2.exe,NULL,NULL,DATA,DATA,DATA
*filename2.exe,NULL,DATA,DATA,NULL,DATA
```

3. replacing all but last 8 characters of first field, logical AND:

```
$ perl -F, -pe 's/^.*?(.{8}),/*$1,/ if ($F[2] ne "NULL" && $F[4] ne "NULL")' input.csv 
1597012957a0dg9a0t593qa_filename1.exe,NULL,NULL,DATA,NULL,DATA
*ame2.exe,NULL,DATA,DATA,DATA,DATA
asvasihtiqsafsoithqwtoihwoi_filename2.exe,NULL,NULL,DATA,DATA,DATA
asvasihtiqsafsoithqwtoihwoi_filename2.exe,NULL,DATA,DATA,NULL,DATA
```

This uses a capture group, `(.{8})`, to extract the last 8 characters of the first field, and use them into the replacement string (`$1`).

4. replacing all but last 8 characters of first field, logical OR:

```
$ perl -F, -pe 's/^.*?(.{8}),/*$1,/ if ($F[2] ne "NULL" || $F[4] ne "NULL")' input.csv 
1597012957a0dg9a0t593qa_filename1.exe,NULL,NULL,DATA,NULL,DATA
*ame2.exe,NULL,DATA,DATA,DATA,DATA
*ame2.exe,NULL,NULL,DATA,DATA,DATA
*ame2.exe,NULL,DATA,DATA,NULL,DATA
```

5. replacing all but the last 8 characters of the **basename** part of the filename (i.e. before the "extension"), logical AND.

```
$ perl -F, -pe 's/^.*?(.{8})\./*$1./ if ($F[2] ne "NULL" && $F[4] ne "NULL")' input.csv 
1597012957a0dg9a0t593qa_filename1.exe,NULL,NULL,DATA,NULL,DATA
*ilename2.exe,NULL,DATA,DATA,DATA,DATA
asvasihtiqsafsoithqwtoihwoi_filename2.exe,NULL,NULL,DATA,DATA,DATA
asvasihtiqsafsoithqwtoihwoi_filename2.exe,NULL,DATA,DATA,NULL,DATA
```

Note: filename "extensions" aren't all that significant in unix & linux filesystems. Also, they're not limited to 3 characters as in ancient MS-DOS FAT filesystems, and there can be more than one - this is true with modern Windows filesystems too.  This version won't work as you probably expect it to if the filename has more than one `.` character in it.

6. it should be obvious by now what the logical OR version will look like.

---

Note: perl arrays start at 0, not 1.  This is why the third field is in `$F[2]` and the fifth field is in `$F[4]`.

Also, I've added two additional lines to your sample input to show the difference between using AND and OR.

```
$ cat input.csv 
1597012957a0dg9a0t593qa_filename1.exe,NULL,NULL,DATA,NULL,DATA
asvasihtiqsafsoithqwtoihwoi_filename2.exe,NULL,DATA,DATA,DATA,DATA
asvasihtiqsafsoithqwtoihwoi_filename2.exe,NULL,NULL,DATA,DATA,DATA
asvasihtiqsafsoithqwtoihwoi_filename2.exe,NULL,DATA,DATA,NULL,DATA
```

The third and fourth lines of the input are the same as your second line, except that on line 3, "DATA" in field 3 has been changed to "NULL, and on line 4, "DATA" in field 5 has been changed to "NULL.

Comment: `.*?(.{8}),` will not do what you think it should. `.+?([^,]{8}),` do it

Comment: Or, add a check that `$F[0]` is atleast 8 character long.

Comment: @guest_7 `.*?(.{8}),` does exactly what I think it does - match zero-or-more of any character, non-greedily, followed by any 8 characters followed by a comma. It works with the provided sample data. It may (or may not) work with the OP's actual data because they haven't been all that clear in defining what it is that they actually want....which is why i wrote a series of examples of how to achieve several different-but-related things - for the OP to tweak to suit their needs - rather than a specific "this is exactly what you want" answer.

Comment: If the input is `$_ = q(1234,5678,f3);` then the regex will break as it is not constrained to look for 8 non commas.

Comment: @guest_7 yes. The rule of [GIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out) is always applicable.  if the OP's actual data does not match their examples, they should say so. or provide relevant examples.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
k=open('filepath','r')
for i in k:
    kospl=i.strip().split(',')
    if (kospl[2] != "NULL"  and kospl[4] != "NULL" and kospl[0] >8):
        lk=len(kospl[0])-13
        k="*."+kospl[0][lk:]+","
        print k+",".join(kospl[1:])
    else:
        print i.strip()
~
```

output

```
1597012957a0dg9a0t593qa_filename1.exe,NULL,NULL,DATA,NULL,DATA
*.filename2.exe,NULL,DATA,DATA,DATA,DATA
```